# Selecting by tags or class in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

basically I would like to select the link underlined whose html is provided in the picture and navigate inside it to get info [image]

How can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that

```py
import selenium
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
URL = 'url'
driver.get(URL)
a = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.profile-link")
href = a.get_attribute("href")
print(href)
```

after click

```py
li_obcject = driver.find_elements_by_id('who-atc-codes')
lst = li_object.find_element_by_tag_name("span").find_elements_by_tag_name("p")

for el in lst:
    print(el.text)
```

Comment: thank you. It works perfectly. Thee very last thing I would like to do after clicking with `a[0].click()` is to get elements inside of them. But maybe I should answer since this is a new question.